# How to check no. of characters in a textview

Tags: android

I have a listview in which data is added from a databse. I have a textview which displays the data.
Is there any way to know how many characters are there in that particular textview.
What I want is Google Keep like UI. if we have only 4-5 characters entered, then the size of the text in the gridview is large. If there is are more characters, like a few words or a sentence, the size of the textview is smaller

Comment: `myTextView.getText().toString().length`?

Comment: Several different ways cause...[Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

Comment: how can i use that length than? I mean I want to do something like this: if (length == x) {textview.size = y}

Comment: I think you should edit your question with what *exactly* it is that you are trying to accomplish and the code you have tried.

Comment: i havent tried nything yet. let me edit my question

Comment: ok. i got what i want. Thank You (y)

Answer (score 1):

```
int length = textViewObj.getText().toString().length();
```

You can get more info about the `getText()` method of `TextView` class in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()):

And in the `String` class [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String a = textview.getText();
int length = a.length( ); // length == 8
```